# Scraping HTML title headers and matching a wordlist - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to Python, the issue I have is:

I want to specify a website and have a Python module (Eg. BeautifulSoup) scrape the title header and print "Bingo" if it matches any words in a wordlist, otherwise print "nothing here"

The code I have is below, any suggestions or ideas on how I can make this work?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Match = ("Whois", "domain", "IP", "search")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.Request("https://whois.domaintools.com/"))
if (soup.title.string in Match):
    print ("Bingo")
else:
    print ("Nothing here!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'the `requests` module:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://whois.domaintools.com/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(r.text)
```

This prints the following message:

```
Please contact memberservices@domaintools.com and reference error #4311
```

I have a sneaking suspicion that this might be because they block scrapers. Indeed, when we specify a user agent similar to that of a browser, it now loads the page correctly. The fixed version, thus, becomes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Match = ("Whois", "domain", "IP", "search")

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://whois.domaintools.com/', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for m in Match:
    if m in soup.title.string:
        print('Bingo!')
        break  # Exit checking loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the UserAgent roadblock would've got me stuck down the track. Much appreciated.